# Sql query to select data in asc desc order with find number in string

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find the number from string with a SQL query so I select data in asc and desc order with this number?

I have table `bf_offers` and a column `title` with values like this:

```
title
---------------
Flat 20% off
Flat 50% off
Upto 40% off
```

I want to find the number like 20, 50 & 40 and arrange title with in desc or asc order. If I set to desc order then data should be ordered like this:

```
title
-----------------
Flat 50% off
Flat 40% off
Upto 20% off
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it-

```
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title,'%',1),2) AS SIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using substring function do this.

```
order by SUBSTRING(title, CHAR_LENGTH(title) - 5,2)
```

or descending

```
order by SUBSTRING(title, CHAR_LENGTH(title) - 5,2) desc
```

Comment: Colum pattern can be diffrent. it is not in fixed patter. it can also like :- 50% off, 50% flat discount etc. @mukesh

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(title, n, 1)
              FROM tablename
              WHERE n <= LEN(title)
                AND SUBSTRING(titale, n, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
              FOR XML PATH('')) AS float)
FROM tablename
```